# How can I set an Office365 mail archive policy for all mailboxes where mails are older than 5 years and size larger than 50GB

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, archive, exchangeonline, office365

How can I set an O365 mail archive policy for all mailboxes where mails are older than 5 years and size larger than 50GB

I have looked up Office365 admin portal, however can't see any options to achieve that
Perhaps powershell command ?

Ideally, I would like this to be an automatic process that applies to all mailboxes. Rather than manually checking the mailbox periodically, the system checks regularly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use MRM policy. It can set to automatically move items that are 5 years old to the user's archive mailbox and Move items to the archive mailbox frees up space in a user's primary mailbox.
For more information ,you can reference this Microsoft Document:[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/set-up-an-archive-and-deletion-policy-for-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exchange Online retention policies to automatically archive messages older than "X" days:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/modify-archive-policies
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/retention-tags-and-policies

Comment: Compliance management > Retention tags, is no longer valid option. MS has obviously moved/renamed this item ?

Comment: Use the Exchange Admin Center. These are Exchange-specific settings, you can't manage them from the main Office 365 admin portal.